# Cannot scroll to bottom wpf

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox, scroll

I have a listbox with objects but I cannot scroll to the bottom of the page. What is the problem? This is the code that I'm using.

```
           <Grid>
                <Image Name="Nietcomment" Source="write.png" Width="70" Margin="350,-850,0,0" Tap="Login_popup" Visibility="Visible"/>
                <Image Name="welcomment" Source="write2.png" Width="70" Margin="350,-850,0,0" Tap="Login_popup_remove" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                <ScrollViewer Name="scrollview" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="0,0,0,0" Foreground="Black">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="NTitelComment" Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="25" Margin="10,0,10,0" Foreground="#FFE5001b"/>
                        <Line Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" X1="0" X2="1" Y1="0" Y2="0" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tijdComment" Text="{Binding}" Margin="50,0,10,0" Foreground="Black"/>
                        <Image Height="20" Width="20" Margin="-380,-20,0,0" Source="/PostDateIcon.png"/>
                        <ListBox Margin="0,0,0,20" Name="lbComments" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
           </Grid>
```

Comment: First, cleanup your code and remove all Margins, and the Stackpanel around your ListBox, that is not needed. You have a `Grid.Row="1"` that is not used etc. Then it will be easier to help out and read your code, also for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a border around your ScrollViewer, can you see if it goes outside of the screen maybe? Will it help to set a fixed height of the Grid or ScrollViewer?
Keep in mind the phone has built in scroll, so your ScrollViewer maybe doesn't play well with it.

Answer (score 0):

With so much fixed margins, your layout will be impossible to manage, especially when dealing with differents screen resolutions and especially with negative margins.
Anyway, right now, you have two scrollviewers, as your listbox contains one as well.
You should disable the listbox scrollviewer or it will prevent your page to scroll.
Just change your listbox:

```
<ListBox 
    Margin="0,0,0,20" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
    Name="lbComments" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

It will disable it's scrollviewer and allow it to scroll with the rest of the page.